# Update Cmdb_ci table of one instance with respect to update of another servicenow instance

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

We have a requirement in which we want to update the cmdb_ci table of one instance of ServiceNow with respect to the create or update in the cmdb_ci of another instance.

If someone creates or updates the ci in **instance 1** the same should get reflected in **instance 2**.

I tried it with a scheduled job but the requirement demands it on live basis.

Answer (score 2):

Use a REST API instead. 
REST documentation is available on developer.servicenow.com. 
To make it instantaneous, you would want to do a push from the instance on which the change occurs rather than a pull from the instance that should receive the change.